# Can I use Git on a mounted drive in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, git, mount

I was just wondering if git can be used on a mounted drive?

I can git init in the drive but when I try to clone/add/push etc I get an error... input/output error.

So I am not sure if what I want to do is possible or not?

I code on a remote server but want to use Git. So I thought if I mounted the drive and accessed it that way, I could still use Git. Maybe not?

Answer (score 1):

All of that should work, but it might be slow.  Why not ssh to the server and run git locally there?

Comment: How would I do that? Never done that before so not really sure!